# How to get IP which is using for internet connection in Delphi

Tags: delphi, networking, winsock

I have a few network adapters in my system:

- WiFI (to my home router)
- VPN connection (using Windows PPTP)
- VPN Connection (OpenVPN)

When I'm only connected to WiFI - my IP address is 192.168.1.101 (gateway 192.168.1.1)
Activating VPN connections brings me next IP's (ex. (PPTP) 192.168.90.101, (OpenVPN) 10.9.0.6)

Question is: How to determine which IP address is "default" for internet connection?

Scenarios:

No 1 - only WiFi - ER (Expected Result): 192.168.1.101

No 2 - WiFi + PPTP (with "Use default gateway on remote network") - ER: 192.168.90.101

No 3 - WiFi + PPTP (without "Use default gateway on remote network") - ER: 192.168.1.101

No 4 - WiFi + OpenVPN - ER: 192.168.1.101

And so on...

Btw. IP from OpenVPN is never returned. This network doesn't route internet connections.

When I use tracert - I can read this information looking on what is first entry in result. But I have to get this information using Delphi or external library used from Delphi app.

I'm using Delphi XE3.

Any ideas? Thanks for help!

PS. [Get information about the installed network adapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378630/get-information-about-the-installed-network-adapters) I tried this solution, but there is no info that NIC is default for internet.

Best regards,
Robert

Answer (score 2):

Open a TidUDPClient and TidUDPServer both with broadcast enabled and with the same port number. Send out a recognizable message on 255.255.255.255 and when it bounces back read the PeerIP from the returned TidSocketHandle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this class that implements traceroute, as except for what traceroute does using ICMP (ping) packets, consulting an external service is the only reliable option I know of.  If your version of Indy doesn't have `TIdTraceRoute` yet, you can use this code that just needs basic ICMP :

```
unit TraceRt; 
interface 
// ===========================================================================
// TRACEROUTE Class
// Mike Heydon Dec 2003
//
// Method
// Trace(IpAddress : string; ResultList : TStrings)
//             Returns semi-colon delimited list of ip routes to target
//             format .. IP ADDRESS; PING TIME MS; TIME TO LIVE; STATUS
//
// Properties
//             IcmpTimeOut : integer (Default = 5000ms)
//             IcmpMaxHops : integer (Default = 40)
// ===========================================================================
uses Forms, Windows, Classes, SysUtils, IdIcmpClient; 
type 
     TTraceRoute = class(TObject) 
     protected 
       procedure ProcessResponse(Status : TReplyStatus); 
       procedure AddRoute(AResponseTime : DWORD; 
                          AStatus: TReplyStatus; const AInfo: string ); 
     private 
       FIcmpTimeOut, 
       FIcmpMaxHops : integer; 
       FResults : TStringList; 
       FICMP : TIdIcmpClient; 
       FPingStart : cardinal; 
       FCurrentTTL : integer; 
       procedure PingTarget; 
     public 
       constructor Create; 
       procedure Trace(const AIpAddress : string; AResultList : TStrings); 
       property IcmpTimeOut : integer read FIcmpTimeOut write FIcmpTimeOut; 
       property IcmpMaxHops : integer read FIcmpMaxHops write FIcmpMaxHops; 
     end; 
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
implementation 
// ========================================
// Create the class and set defaults
// ========================================
constructor TTraceRoute.Create; 
begin 
  IcmpTimeOut := 5000; 
  IcmpMaxHops := 40; 
end; 
// =============================================
// Use Indy component to ping hops to target
// =============================================
procedure TTraceRoute.PingTarget; 
var wOldMode : DWORD; 
begin 
  Application.ProcessMessages; 
  inc(FCurrentTTL); 
  if FCurrentTTL < FIcmpMaxHops then begin 
    FICMP.TTL  := FCurrentTTL; 
    FICMP.ReceiveTimeout := FIcmpTimeOut; 
    FPingStart := GetTickCount; 
    wOldMode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS); 
    try 
      FICMP.Ping; 
      ProcessResponse(FICMP.ReplyStatus); 
    except 
      FResults.Add('0.0.0.0;0;0;ERROR'); 
    end; 
    SetErrorMode(wOldMode); 
  end 
  else 
    FResults.Add('0.0.0.0;0;0;MAX HOPS EXCEEDED'); 
end; 
// ============================================================
// Add the ping reply status data to the returned stringlist
// ============================================================
procedure TTraceRoute.AddRoute(AResponseTime : DWORD; 
                               AStatus: TReplyStatus; 
                               const AInfo: string ); 
begin 
  FResults.Add(AStatus.FromIPAddress + ';' + 
               IntToStr(GetTickCount - AResponseTime) + ';' + 
               IntToStr(AStatus.TimeToLive) + ';' + AInfo); 
end; 
// ============================================================
// Process the ping reply status record and add to stringlist
// ============================================================
procedure TTraceRoute.ProcessResponse(Status : TReplyStatus); 
begin 
  case Status.ReplyStatusType of 
    // Last Leg - Terminate Trace
    rsECHO : AddRoute(FPingStart,Status,'OK'); 
    // More Hops to go - Continue Pinging
    rsErrorTTLExceeded :  begin 
                            AddRoute(FPingStart,Status,'OK'); 
                            PingTarget; 
                          end; 
    // Error conditions - Terminate Trace
    rsTimeOut : AddRoute(FPingStart,Status,'TIMEOUT'); 
    rsErrorUnreachable : AddRoute(FPingStart,Status,'UNREACHABLE'); 
    rsError : AddRoute(FPingStart,Status,'ERROR'); 
  end; 
end; 
// ======================================================
// Trace route to target IP address
// Results returned in semi-colon delimited stringlist
// IP; TIME MS; TIME TO LIVE; STATUS
// ======================================================
procedure TTraceRoute.Trace(const AIpAddress : string; 
                            AResultList : TStrings); 
begin 
  FICMP := TIdIcmpClient.Create(nil); 
  FICMP.Host := AIpAddress; 
  FResults := TStringList(AResultList); 
  FResults.Clear; 
  FCurrentTTL := 0; 
  PingTarget; 
  FICMP.Free; 
end; 
{eof} 
end.
```

Comment: It won't compile - `if FCurrentTTL FICMP.TTL  := FCurrentTTL;`. Besides, isn't that what is already wrapped in `TIdTraceRoute` ?

Comment: @TLama should be better now.  Unfortunately I have no Delphi compiler available here to check it, and IIRC the older Indy's lacked that traceroute facility.  I know this isn't OP's case (XE3), but it might be helpful for people stuck with older toolchains that stumble upon this question.

Comment: Thank you (all) for the advice! I tried to use TIdTraceRoute but it raise EIdSocketError #10013 Access denied. :/

Comment: @robertw, lol, right now I was writing that it requires administrator elevation on Vista above systems. You'd need to use a method [`like this`](https://code.google.com/p/projects-stackoverflow-tlama/source/browse/trunk/17084031/PingUnit.pas) for ping. But if you'd decide to use it, see [`this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084031/how-to-define-uchar-pointer-32-and-void-pointer-32-types-in-delphi#comment25601943_17084181).

Comment: @TLama :) Even if I use admin - it doesn't work. Every replay status is time out...

Comment: @robertw, the unit I linked is just for ping, which doesn't require elevation of the process. It's not for tracing. With my comment I wanted to say that if you'd like to avoid elevation of your process when using `TIdTraceRoute`, you would need to modify the component to use the way for ping from that unit. I hope I didn't mislead you...

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the routing information by `route print` from the command prompt.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.69.1    192.168.69.15     20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.69.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.69.15    276
    192.168.69.15  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.69.15    276
   192.168.69.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.69.15    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.69.15    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.69.15    276
```

The "internet" has network destination `0.0.0.0`. So you just have to lookup, which interface and gateway is resposible for that destination (here `192.168.69.15` via `192.168.69.1`).

This information can also be retrieved by WMI [`Win32_IP4RouteTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

A good starting point for WMI queries with delphi is [WMI Delphi Code Creator](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/wmi-delphi-code-creator/)

Comment: It would seem it's a bit more complicated. When connected with VPN that's using remote gateway, there are more than one 0.0.0.0 entries. Remote route shown with an "on-link" gateway.

Comment: I am a bit rusty on this topic, but if there are multiple entries I thought you should consider the one which has the lowest metric.

Comment: Yes there is some more work to do. Also the metric can be the same and then you have to check the binding sequence